# Updated django models can't update

Tags: python, django, models

So I recently made some minor changes to my Django models (added a field). Something I've done plenty of times in the past. Now when I got to makemigrations on the server I get the following errors. I have no idea what they mean or where to start diagnosing the problem. Everything works fine on my local machine.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Ex                 ception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
  File "/home/pentaqueue/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassiopeia/type/api/                 rates.py", line 82, in _reset
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
  File "/home/pentaqueue/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassiopeia/type/api/                 rates.py", line 82, in _reset
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

EDIT: added the models.py code as well per request.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Virtues(models.Model):
    summoner_id = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    summoner_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    virtue_teamwork = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    virtue_proficiency = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    virtue_friendliness = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    pass

class championDB(models.Model):
    summoner_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    summoner_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    champion_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    champion_winratio = models.FloatField(default=0)
    champion_gamesplayed = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    champion_kda = models.FloatField(default=0)
    pass

class gamesDB(models.Model):
    summoner_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    game_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pass

class summonerDB(models.Model):
    summoner_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    summoner_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ranked_winratio = models.FloatField(default=0)
    ranked_gamesplayed = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    unranked_winratio = models.FloatField(default=0)
    unranked_gamesplayed = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    virtues = models.ManyToManyField(Virtues)
    champions = models.ManyToManyField(championDB)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(gamesDB)

class SummonerModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    validation_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="XXXXXXXX")
    validated = models.CharField(max_length=3, default="yes")
    summoner_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="NA")
    pass
```

Comment: What's in your str/unicode method of the model?

Comment: Also post the model code please.

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596918/python-exception-in-thread-thread-1-most-likely-raised-during-interpreter-shutd?answertab=votes#tab-top) will help you

Comment: Not sure what i'm supposed to get out of that link vinay. I am not using daemon?